# Load Image from Website into Tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to load images from a website into a tableview. I can load an image stored in the project, but am unable to get image from the web. I know I am missing something here. Any ideas?

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:
@"http://www.website.com/thumbs/img_10.jpg"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: See the LazyTableImages sample app. It shows how to properly load images from the Internet and put them in table cells.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy, I am returning all of the rest of the content for the tableview in JSON format, is there a "lazier" way to do it since Im pulling the URL to the image from JSON?

Comment: You have to load the image data yourself with a web request (or use one of the URL functions).  You can't use a URL with imageNamed:.

Comment: @Brandon Once you get the URL from the JSON data, use it to load the image from the Internet. This is where the example I referenced will help. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/53789a67f8fffd8ede2ea118165ff962?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But get image synchronously using this way will block your UI. You'd better get image asynchronously. Send out a request and after get the image update your UI in your request delegate method.

Comment: Thanks @sunkehappy, the code you gave me works, but I am not sure how to get the images asynchronously. I have all the cell data, including the URL to the image stored in a JSON array. The code you gave me works, but it is a bit slow and causes the tableview to be very "sticky". Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html. Have you seen this project? It use `NSURLConnection` you can use it or other library like ASIHTTPConnection or RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"give your url hrere."]];

 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image =image;
```